# JsonSerializer.Serialize only serializes the properties of the base class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to have a base class that overrides `ToString` by converting any objects that inherits it to JSON. When running this program, it seems like `this` in the context of the base object is not the full object, but instead only the base object itself.

Is it possible to refer to the inherited object from the base object?

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Test
{
    public class BaseModel 
    {
        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
        }
    }

    public class Data : BaseModel 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new Data { Name = "Test", Value = 42 };
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because `JsonSerialize.Serialize<TValue>(TValue, [JsonSerializerOptions])` is a generic method, and, due to type interference, your code is compiled as:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize<BaseModel>(this);
}
```

In this case, the solution is to use the non-generic overload `JsonSerialize.Serialize(object, Type, [JsonSerializerOptions])` instead:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, this.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `ToString` method in the derived class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
}
```

Comment: Well, the point here was to avoid defining the exact same method in every subclass. Is that not possible?

Comment: Without overriding not possible. one thing you can do that, call the base class method from child class method and call that child class method on the child object.